# The vue frontend I made fails to compile with one error saying "this relative module module was not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I made a vue frontend to talk with my spring backend which works fine, but after making the frontend and compiling it compiles to 98% and with an error message:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
> 11:24:51
>
> This relative module was not found:
>
> - ../services/TutorialDataService in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/TutorialsList.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

I don't know what's wrong but i've remade the whole project three time now and it still come back with the same error message. can some help me?

here is main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

here is the TutorialDataService.js

```
import http from "../http-common";

class TutorialDataService {
  getAll() {
    return http.get("/tutorials");
  }

  get(id) {
    return http.get(`/tutorials/${id}`);
  }

  create(data) {
    return http.post("/tutorials", data);
  }

  update(id, data) {
    return http.put(`/tutorials/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id) {
    return http.delete(`/tutorials/${id}`);
  }

  deleteAll() {
    return http.delete(`/tutorials`);
  }

  findByTitle(title) {
    return http.get(`/tutorials?title=${title}`);
  }
}

export default new TutorialDataService();
```

here is the AddTutorial.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="submit-form mt-3 mx-auto">
    <p class="headline">Add Tutorial</p>

    <div v-if="!submitted">
      <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="tutorial.title"
          :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Title is required']"
          label="Title"
          required
        ></v-text-field>

        <v-text-field
          v-model="tutorial.description"
          :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Description is required']"
          label="Description"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-form>

      <v-btn color="primary" class="mt-3" @click="saveTutorial">Submit</v-btn>
    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <v-card class="mx-auto">
        <v-card-title>
          Submitted successfully!
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-subtitle>
          Click the button to add new Tutorial.
        </v-card-subtitle>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="success" @click="newTutorial">Add</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialDataService";

export default {
  name: "add-tutorial",
  data() {
    return {
      tutorial: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        description: "",
        published: false,
      },
      submitted: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveTutorial() {
      var data = {
        title: this.tutorial.title,
        description: this.tutorial.description,
      };

      TutorialDataService.create(data)
        .then((response) => {
          this.tutorial.id = response.data.id;
          console.log(response.data);
          this.submitted = true;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    newTutorial() {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.tutorial = {};
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.submit-form {
  max-width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

here is the Tutorial.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="currentTutorial" class="edit-form py-3">
    <p class="headline">Edit Tutorial</p>

    <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="currentTutorial.title"
        :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Title is required']"
        label="Title"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
        v-model="currentTutorial.description"
        :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Description is required']"
        label="Description"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <label><strong>Status:</strong></label>
      {{ currentTutorial.published ? "Published" : "Pending" }}

      <v-divider class="my-5"></v-divider>

      <v-btn v-if="currentTutorial.published"
        @click="updatePublished(false)"
        color="primary" small class="mr-2"
      >
        UnPublish
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn v-else
        @click="updatePublished(true)"
        color="primary" small class="mr-2"
      >
        Publish
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn color="error" small class="mr-2" @click="deleteTutorial">
        Delete
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn color="success" small @click="updateTutorial">
        Update
      </v-btn>
    </v-form>

    <p class="mt-3">{{ message }}</p>
  </div>

  <div v-else>
    <p>Please click on a Tutorial...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialDataService";

export default {
  name: "tutorial",
  data() {
    return {
      currentTutorial: null,
      message: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getTutorial(id) {
      TutorialDataService.get(id)
        .then((response) => {
          this.currentTutorial = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    updatePublished(status) {
      var data = {
        id: this.currentTutorial.id,
        title: this.currentTutorial.title,
        description: this.currentTutorial.description,
        published: status,
      };

      TutorialDataService.update(this.currentTutorial.id, data)
        .then((response) => {
          this.currentTutorial.published = status;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    updateTutorial() {
      TutorialDataService.update(this.currentTutorial.id, this.currentTutorial)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.message = "The tutorial was updated successfully!";
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    deleteTutorial() {
      TutorialDataService.delete(this.currentTutorial.id)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.$router.push({ name: "tutorials" });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.message = "";
    this.getTutorial(this.$route.params.id);
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.edit-form {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

here is the the TutorialsList.vue

```
<template>
  <v-row align="center" class="list px-3 mx-auto">
    <v-col cols="12" md="8">
      <v-text-field v-model="title" label="Search by Title"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-btn small @click="searchTitle">
        Search
      </v-btn>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
      <v-card class="mx-auto" tile>
        <v-card-title>Tutorials</v-card-title>

        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="tutorials"
          disable-pagination
          :hide-default-footer="true"
        >
          <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
            <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editTutorial(item.id)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            <v-icon small @click="deleteTutorial(item.id)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>

        <v-card-actions v-if="tutorials.length > 0">
          <v-btn small color="error" @click="removeAllTutorials">
            Remove All
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialDataService";
export default {
  name: "tutorials-list",
  data() {
    return {
      tutorials: [],
      title: "",
      headers: [
        { text: "Title", align: "start", sortable: false, value: "title" },
        { text: "Description", value: "description", sortable: false },
        { text: "Status", value: "status", sortable: false },
        { text: "Actions", value: "actions", sortable: false },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    retrieveTutorials() {
      TutorialDataService.getAll()
        .then((response) => {
          this.tutorials = response.data.map(this.getDisplayTutorial);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    refreshList() {
      this.retrieveTutorials();
    },

    removeAllTutorials() {
      TutorialDataService.deleteAll()
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.refreshList();
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    searchTitle() {
      TutorialDataService.findByTitle(this.title)
        .then((response) => {
          this.tutorials = response.data.map(this.getDisplayTutorial);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    editTutorial(id) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "tutorial-details", params: { id: id } });
    },

    deleteTutorial(id) {
      TutorialDataService.delete(id)
        .then(() => {
          this.refreshList();
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    getDisplayTutorial(tutorial) {
      return {
        id: tutorial.id,
        title: tutorial.title.length > 30 ? tutorial.title.substr(0, 30) + "..." : tutorial.title,
        description: tutorial.description.length > 30 ? tutorial.description.substr(0, 30) + "..." : tutorial.description,
        status: tutorial.published ? "Published" : "Pending",
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.retrieveTutorials();
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.list {
  max-width: 750px;
}
</style>
```

here is the router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      alias: "/tutorials",
      name: "tutorials",
      component: () => import("./components/TutorialsList")
    },
    {
      path: "/tutorials/:id",
      name: "tutorial-details",
      component: () => import("./components/Tutorial")
    },
    {
      path: "/add",
      name: "add",
      component: () => import("./components/AddTutorial")
    }
  ]
});
```

and here is the http-commons.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8081/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

and here are my dependecies in package.json

```
{
  "name": "vuetify-table-example-2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addTutorial.vue, in the  tag, try changing your import from:

`import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialDataService";`

To:

`import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialDataService.js";`

Adding that `.js` file extension at the end

Answer (score 0):

The file structure of the tutorial is different than what is being imported, try using this for the TutorialDataService imports under the components:

import TutorialDataService from "../../services/TutorialDataService";

Another error you may run into is the http-common.js import under services/TutorialDataService.js should be:

import http from "../src/http-common";